# How to feed one data class with another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to construct a simple application to make operations like comparing, adding objects to Hall of Fame list, etc. I'm pretty sure the `Owner` class is built correctly, but when feeding the `HallOfFame` objects with `Owner` objects, I get many errors.

The app looks like this so far:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Owner:
    name: str
    qty_of_belongings: int

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.qty_of_belongings == other.qty_of_belongings

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {str(self.qty_of_belongings)}"


@dataclass
class HallOfFame:
    owner: Owner
    hall_of_fame: List[Owner]

    def add(self, owner):
        return self.append(owner)
```

Defining `Owner` objects and basic operations, like printing or comparing, works just fine:

```py
o1 = Owner("Grace", 5)
o2 = Owner("Sharon", 3)
```

But when I go one step further and try to define anything related to `HallOfFame`, like this:

```py
hof = HallOfFame()
hof.add(o1)
```

problems start to appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/ranks_2.py", line 29, in <module>
    hof = HallOfFame()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'owner' and 'hall_of_fame'
```

I know it's a rookie problem, but somehow I can't embrace the concept of data classes... What should be done to make it work as intended and e.g. add owners to the hall of fame list?

Comment: Default constructor expects parameters to initialize your class variables.  Along the same lines you have it in `Owner`.  If that's not what you want - create your own `__init__()`.

Comment: @PM77-1 he could create `__post_init__` because `__init__` would be overwritten. @AbreQueVoy I don't think the second one should be dataclass, I recommend you create a normal class. dataclasses are usually for when you want to just store some data, like `struct`s in other languages

Comment: You could always make `hall_of_fame` an optional value that gets initialized to `[]` if not passed. The `owner` seems like it should be either required or removed from the definition altogether. (The semantics of both fields are unclear.)

Comment: @Superior: thanks for hint: making the HallOfFame a normal class made things much clearer. If you could post an answer with an example, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second class doesn't look like it should be dataclass

You can just make normal class
and it's `__init__` and other methods that you need (`__str__`, `__eq__`, ...)

dataclasses are made to be for storing data
like `struct`s in other languages
with built-in functionality (hash, equality, ...)

I also wrongly commented that `__init__` would be overwritten
It wouldn't, but it is recommended to use `__post_init__` instead
because `dataclass` will make a convenient constructor